# Fluid compression against wall

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure, flow, navier-stokes

A compressible fluid within a fixed cubic container is compressed at time $t=0$ by a spatially homogeneous force against one face of the cube. After a long time the mass distribution of the fluid should develop a gradient along the direction of the force. The equilibrium mass distribution should be an exponential, in a similar way to the barometric equation.

But directly after turning on the force, and before the fluid has found the equilibrium distribution, intuitively there should be some oscillations between the two faces of the cube, against which the fluid is compressed.

Could anyone please indicate if this is treated somewhere? This seems to be a simple case but I could not find any similar example due to my lack of background in fluid dynamics.

Comment: Navier-Stokes equations should describe this. However, the solution might be only numerically possible.

Comment: Yes, could you please suggest a keyword that might lead me to the right place in some textbook ? In fact I have written down NS equations and started numerically simulating this. I took the momentum equation in one dimension with the pressure drop and with an ideal gas expression for the pressure, and the continuity equation for the mass. But this seems to be simple and I thought someone else could have done this.

Comment: Are you assuming the fluid to be an ideal gas at fixed temperature? In general, for closure, you need to also add the equation of state relating pressure to density.

Comment: I am not aware of any sources, where this specific problem is addressed, but the Navier-Stokes equations for this case should be quite straightforward with the force acting in only one dimension. I would suggest you look into standard fluid mechanics books, e.g. Frank M. White. And then reasnoable set up the conservation laws according to N-S.